error while export data to csv from mysql in nodejs
i want to export data to excel from mysql using nodejs currently i have 5M+ records in database and throw error kill but when i have around 1.7M records at that time this is working so i think i need to handle using stream so i have try using stream also but it is not working.
exports.exportdatatocsv = async (req, res) => {
  con.query(
    "SELECT sender_name, table_name FROM sender_tbl",
    function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        return;
      }

      var mysqlData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      var workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({ stream: res });

      mysqlData.forEach((sender, index) => {
        var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(
          sender.sender_name.substring(0, 31)
        );

        con.query(
          `SELECT * FROM ${sender.table_name} ORDER BY id DESC`,
          function (error, tableData) {
            if (error) {
              console.error(error);
              res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
              return;
            }

            var fileHeader = [
              "message",
              "info",
              "credit/debit",
              "amount",
              "netbal",
            ];
            worksheet.addRow(fileHeader);

            tableData.forEach((row) => {
              worksheet.addRow([
                row.message,
                row.info,
                row.isdebit ? "debit" : "credit",
                row.amount,
                row.netbal,
              ]);
            });

            if (index === mysqlData.length - 1) {
              workbook
                .commit()
                .then(function () {
                  res.status(200).end();
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  res
                    .status(500)
                    .send("Error occurred while generating Excel file");
                });
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  );
};


What kind of an error do you get: timeout or out of memory? I would not try to export 5m+ rows in a http request-response cycle, I would use some kind of background processing solution with notification to users when the export is done.

it is throw error killed means out of memory

Use paging then - select a chunk of the rows, export them into a file, select another chunk ... and so on. But again, I would not put such code into a request-response cycle if you expect to have millions of rows.
